# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Graphic Design's [fourth moderator election](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators is:

[image: Emilie]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4706383903588352/0).

Answer (score 19):

Congrats Emilie!!! Enjoy your ♦

It was a good race, thanks for stepping up!

## :D

Answer (score 13):

It's an honor to have been elected to be part of the moderator team and I am humbled by the community's vote of confidence. I look forward to learn the ropes and help this community thrive.

A big thank you to WELZ for running in this election. You have been contributing so much since you have joined and I hope this continues! Last but most importantly, thanks to all who have exercised their right to vote!